# Fatal error: Class 'ulangStream' not found Umi cms

Tags: php, umi

Добрый день! Вдруг появилась ошибка при попытке зайти в админку:

> Fatal error: Class 'ulangStream' not found in /home/unadearu/public_html/classes/system/subsystems/cmsController/cmsController.php on line 959

На сайт:

> Fatal error: Class 'ulangStream' not found in /home/unadearu/public_html/libs/lib.php on line 140

PHP инфо: http://unadea.ru/phpinfo.php

Перерыла интернет, ничего подобного не нашла.

Comment: а как мы сможем помочь ? раз нету класса, так создайте его, а если это библиотека, обновите версию библиотеки или правильно подключите. В любом случаи нужно больше информации

Comment: Здесь можно проверить, подходит ли хостинг под системные требования: http://www.umi-cms.ru/support/umi_cms_php_hosting/proverka_hostinga/
Класс ulangStream находится в файле /classes/system/subsystems/streams/ulang/ulangStream.php
Рекомендую обновить систему или откатиться на рабочий бекап.

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка может возникать при повреждении файла config.ini
В нем прописаны пути к необходимым классам и библиотекам.